# Typescript generating redundant variable

Tags: javascript, compilation, typescript

Consider the following Typescript code:

```
module demoAppModule{
    'use strict';

    export module nest{
        export var hello = function () {
            alert('Hello!');
        };
    }
}

demoAppModule.nest.hello();
```

After transpiling we have the following javascript code:

```
var demoAppModule;
(function (demoAppModule) {
    'use strict';

    (function (nest) {
        nest.hello = function () {
            alert('Hello!');
        };
    })(demoAppModule.nest || (demoAppModule.nest = {}));
    var nest = demoAppModule.nest;
})(demoAppModule || (demoAppModule = {}));

demoAppModule.nest.hello();
```

Why is this line generated? It hurts my eyes.

```
var nest = demoAppModule.nest;
```

Comment: That line seems completely useless to me. The only reason I can think of is that the compiler thinks that the parameter `nest` must be defined before the function `hello`, however the assignment takes place at the very bottom and then does nothing with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Its needed to access the module variable locally. E.g.

```
module demoAppModule{
    'use strict';

    export module nest{
        export var hello = function () {
            alert('Hello!');
        };
    }

    // The following would not be possible without that line 
    console.log(nest.hello);
}

demoAppModule.nest.hello();
```

**Longer Answer:** Its similar to the var added before a module e.g. notice `var x`:

```
// TypeScript 
module x{export var foo;}
// Generated JavaScript 
var x;
(function (x) {
    x.foo;
})(x || (x = {}));
```

But when you are inside a module + export a module the `var` needs to be added to `outermodule.innermodule` so you do not do `var innermodule` upfront. You add it to `outermodule` and then create a local variable to point to the `innermodule` which you can see in the generated javascript:

```
// Notice var here 
var demoAppModule;
(function (demoAppModule) {
    'use strict';

    // Notice no var here 
    (function (nest) {
        nest.hello = function () {
            alert('Hello!');
        };
    })(demoAppModule.nest || (demoAppModule.nest = {}));
    // Notice var assinged afterwards
    var nest = demoAppModule.nest;

    // The following would not be possible without that line
    console.log(nest.hello);
})(demoAppModule || (demoAppModule = {}));

demoAppModule.nest.hello();
```

Comment: Thank you. Reading this I realize that had I used nest afterwards, like the logging in your example, it wouldn't have looked so unnecessary.